# Java String Object creation : Execution time difference in both Java & in JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I did a time difference test between java and jni, by creating a string object (new String("some string");) for 100 million times. When testing this via Java code it took around 1 second to execute. But when testing it via Jni code it took around 31 seconds.

For the JNI part, do I need to change the jni code design or need to add additional compiler options to increase the execution speed?

**Environment:**
Mingw (32)
Windows 8.1 (64)
Java 1.8 (32)
C++ Compiler option : -shared -m32 -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias

**(Needed part of the code in each files given below)**

**C++ File :**

```
class javaString {
    jclass cls;
    jmethodID method;
    jstring strNew;
    jobject obj;
public:
    javaString() {
    }
    void myInit(JNIEnv *env) {
        jclass cls1 = env-> FindClass("java/lang/String");
       cls = (jclass) env->NewGlobalRef(cls1);
       env->DeleteLocalRef(cls1);
       method = env->GetMethodID(cls, "<init>", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    }

void myCall(JNIEnv *env, long lng) {
    strNew = env->NewStringUTF("Apple");
    for (long i = 0; i < lng; i++) {
        obj = env->NewObject(cls, method, strNew);
        env->DeleteLocalRef(obj);
    }
    env->DeleteLocalRef(strNew);
    env->DeleteGlobalRef(cls);
}
};

javaString objStr;

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_c_wrapperforjavaclass_clsNative_fnInit
(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    objStr.myInit(env);
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_c_wrapperforjavaclass_clsNative_fnCall
(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint a) {
     long lng = a;
     objStr.myCall(env, lng);
}
```

**Java File :**

```
public class clsNative {
    public native void fnInit();
    public native void fnCall(int a);
    public void fnProcess2(int a){
        for(int i=0;i<a;i++){
            String str = new String("Apple");
            str=null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Java File (Test) :**

```
clsNative a = new clsNative();
        boolean blnJNITest=true;
        String s1, s2;

        s1 = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toLocaleString();
        int ii = 100000000; //100 million
        if (blnJNITest) {
            a.fnInit();
            a.fnCall(ii);
        } else {
            a.fnProcess2(ii);
        }
        s2 = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toLocaleString();
        System.out.println(s1);
        System.out.println(s2);
```

In the place of string object (java/lang/String), i have tried the below too

1. StringBuilder strObj = New StringBuilder(int capacity = 100);
2. Integer intObj = New Integer(int value = 100);

In all the cases it is taking around same time.

Comment: Your example clearly shows that transitioning between bytecode and native code is a fairly expensive action, so I'd recommend to use JNI only for things that cannot be done natively in Java (like low-level device or OS interaction), or long calculations where the incurred transition penalty is outweighed by the performance gains, for example.

Comment: You don't do the same things in your Java code and JNI code. Anyway, what happens when you use the `NewStringUTF` JNI API for "creating" a string (coupled with `DeleteLocalRef`)?

Comment: @manuell. Thanks. Handled the DeleteLocalRef in the fncall method.

Comment: Your code is invalid. You're not supposed to store a `JNIEnv*` between JNI calls, or call a constructor more than once per object. The result you have obtained is of zero interest or relevance.

Comment: @EJP, Thanks. The code modified to not storing the JNIEnv* between JNI calls.

Comment: @JamesZ, just asking this to understand it, is there any difference between 10 crore & 100 million when writing?

Comment: @Jeet Yes, the difference that million is a universal measurement and crore is Indian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But in pure Java, the optimizing compiler can "understand" that string is created to be destroyed immediately, and legitimately do nothing. When JNI is involved, neither Java nor C may avoid performing every step.

Comment: "the optimizing compiler can understand that string is created to be destroyed immediately" Do you mean this in the sense that string are immutable?

Comment: No, I mean that Java knows exactly that the string scope is one line only.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the code as below the execution time changed from 31 seconds to around 9 seconds.

**C++ File :**

```
void myInit(JNIEnv *env) {
    jclass cls1 = env-> FindClass("java/lang/String");
    cls = (jclass) env->NewGlobalRef(cls1);
    env->DeleteLocalRef(cls1);
    method = env->GetMethodID(cls, "<init>", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
}

void myCall(JNIEnv *env, long lng) {
    strNew = env->NewStringUTF("Apple");
    jobjectArray objarr = env->NewObjectArray(lng, cls,strNew);
    if (objarr != NULL) {
        cout << "Array constructed" << endl;
        for (long i = 0; i < lng; i++) {
            obj = env->GetObjectArrayElement(objarr, i);
            env->DeleteLocalRef(obj);
        }
    } else {
        cout << "Array construction failed" << endl;
    }
    env->DeleteLocalRef(strNew);
    env->DeleteLocalRef(objarr); /*Not sure is this 2nd line need*/
    env->DeleteGlobalRef(cls);
}
```

**Java File (Test) :**

```
    int ii = 10000000; //10 million
    if (blnJNITest) {
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){ //call 10 times
            a.fnInit();
            a.fnCall(ii);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's wrong to release the class global reference in loop

Comment: @AlexCohn, Global reference release happening outside the loop only. Every time created in the Jni call myInit() and released at the end of myCall(). Here the global reference (jclass) work as cache between multiple Jni calls. Or do you mean frequent creation and deletion of the global references should not be happen (with minimum time gap)?

Comment: OK, once per 10^7 does not really matter